# What is this problem asking? (limits of functions)

Tags: limits

I was asked to prove or find a counterexample of the statement "Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and let $x_k=f(\dfrac{1}{k})$. Then $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k)=\lim_{t\to0} f(t)$." I'm not sure what the statement is saying. If anyone could explain it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, that it shouldn't be $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$ ?

Comment: It might be. I'm just typing this from my professor's work sheet.

Comment: Where does $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k  $ go? Does it go to the same value as $\lim_{t \to 0} t$

That is, assuming what LeBtz says is true

Comment: @kmeis Would the statement make any sense if it were as how I typed it?

Comment: The statement does make sense as something that could be proven or disproven. Is there a particular part of it that is troubling you?

Comment: @AMPerrine I don't understand the equivalence of the limits

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of limits being used in the statement
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=\lim_{t\to 0} f(t).$$
On the left we have a sequence: 
$$f(x_1), f(x_2), f(x_3), \ldots$$
to which we might apply the definition of $x_k$ to rewrite as
$$f(f(1)), f(f(1/2), f(f(1/3)), \ldots$$
The limit of this sequence is given by $L$ if for every real number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n > N$, we have $|f(f(1/n) − L| < \epsilon$.

On the right, we have the limit of a function, which is given by $K$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $0<|t−0|<\delta$, the inequality $|f(t)−K|<\epsilon$ holds.

So the question is asking you to determine whether, for any arbitrary function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the limits $K$ and $L$ here must be equal.

For a concrete example of what's going on, consider the function $f(x)=x$. Then $f(f(1/k))=f(1/k)=1/k$, so the sequence is just
$$1,1/2,1/3,\ldots$$
and it is easy to show that the limit is zero  by taking $N\geq 1/\epsilon$.
On the other hand $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t)$ is also zero, since in the definition of the limit we can always just take $\delta=\epsilon$. So for this particular function, the statement holds. Does it hold for all others?